# Raising a property change event for class object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class as follows:

```
public class UserData : INotifyPropertyChnaged
{
    public string strUserName;
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return strUserName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref strUserName, value); }
    }

    private string strPhoneNumber;
    public string UserPhoneNumber
    {
        get { return strPhoneNumber; }
        set { SetProperty(ref strPhoneNumber, value); }
    }

    private List<UserMailID> listUserMailID;
    public List<UserMailID> ListOfUserMailID
    {
        get { return listUserMailID; }
        set { SetProperty(ref listUserMailID, value); }
    }
}
```

I'm accessing this class at some location and this class object I am binding to my view:

```
private UserData cActiverUser;
public UserData ActiverUser
{
    get { return cActiverUser; }
    set { SetProperty(ref cActiverUser , value); }
}
```

Suppose there is UserName field in my view; my data binding goes like this:

```
TextBox.Text="{Binding ActiverUser.StrUserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

Binding works well, but I am unable to raise the property changed event when I change this user name field on my view.  I have tried setting `Mode="TwoWay"` also.

Comment: Are you using a MVVM framework (just based on the way code is written) or is this something you rolled on your own?  I'm asking, because I don't know how you're handling your `PropertyChanged` event.  We need to see what `SetProperty(...)` does.

Comment: I've never used SetProperty, but per documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn736263%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx it seems to take a reference to the property. Not the backing field.

Comment: Yes I'm following MVVM pattern.

Comment: Here is my SetProperty implementation

Comment: Where is here?  You didn't post it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Prism, derive `UserData` and whatever class has `UserData` as its property from `BindableBase`, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but also lets you use `SetProperty(...)`.  I'm not even sure how you were able to get it to work before, but I suspect you're not showing us your original code, since you misspelled `INotifyPropertyChanged` -- `INotifyPropertyCh`**na**`ged`.

Additionally, are you actually instantiating the object?  Don't forget to do that.

Lastly, you're binding to `ActiverUser.StrUserName`, but `UserData` does not have a property `StrUserName`.  It has `UserName`, which is what you want to bind to.

Answer (score 1):

In your XAML binding, try setting `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True`, or if that doesn't work `NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True`.

I had the same issue with a project I did a while ago, and it was one of those that got it working.

Also on this line:

```
public string strUserName;
```

Should this be private? and you should be specifying the binding as `UserName`, not `strUserName`?

I believe the bindings are also case sensitive.